# Ember.js after transition from callback

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'd like to execute a function after the view has loaded transitioning from a specific route.

Does Ember have a callback for this?

I can get it to work if I do a `setTimeout` on the `click` event of all anchors on that route:

```
didInsertElement: ->
    $('a').on 'click', (e) ->
      setTimeout ->
        console.log $(":hover")
      , 1000
```

But setTimeout isn't reliable.

Comment: The didInsertElement is the event triggered when the view is appended in the dom. So I don't understand why you are using the setTimeout.

Comment: By transitioning from a particular rote, do you mean, when you're in one route and you switch to another?

Comment: Such as I just came to the comments route from the login route (and I only set the hover because I'm coming from login)

Answer (score 1):

If you initiated the transition yourself by calling `transitionTo` you're able to use promises, since the `transitionTo` method returns a `Promise` as you can read in this post from **machty** which gives a very good explanation & insight of the "router facelift": https://gist.github.com/machty/5723945